# Link to External Data using URL to CSV file

Tags: csv, openoffice-calc

I am using OpenOffice Calc 4.1.1 on Windows 7.

I am trying to use Link to External Data to load an external CSV file from a gaming website Wowuction.com. If I open the URL in my browser I get a CSV file saved to disk.  But when I use that exact same URL in the "URL of external data source" box and hit enter, there is a short pause like its loading, but then nothing happens.  Nothing appears in the "Available tables/ranges" box, the OK button is still disabled.

Does OpenOffice Calc not support CSV as an external data source?

Comment: Proxy issue? If not - could you provide a test url of a csv file?

Comment: You need to create an account (free) to get token for the url.  You can find the url under the "Resources>Data Export" menu. Here is a sample with my token taken out: http://www.wowuction.com/us/whisperwind/alliance/Tools/RealmDataExportGetFileStatic?type=csv&dl=true&token=<your token here>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Calc doesn't support loading a CSV file externally, only HTML, ODS, XLS, maybe another.

**But if** you are confortable writing a dos script, you can download the CSV file and convert it to HTML continuously. Then you can just direct the 'Link to External Data' to you local HTML file.

[It's been done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062271/libreoffice-link-to-external-data/37482329#37482329) on ubuntu linux, in case you want a little reference.

Comment: That helps.  Especially since I would likely use Cygwin on my PC, and able to run Bash scripts.