# LibreOffice Link to external data

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a problem to import into LibreOffice an external csv .
[image]

I press OK, and everything is formatted correctly

[image]

After the "ok" button is disabled and I can not continue..

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: As far as i see, you can't use csv as source for external data. Only html, xls and ods are supported. Alternatively, you may try Menu `Insert` -> `Sheet from file` (see [this Q/A from ask.lo](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/27063/external-data-source-with-csv/))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Calc can't import CSV from external data source, only HTML, ODF, and a few others.

If you need to import the file just once, download the CSV, then use the 'Insert Sheet' option.

You don't mention what OS you're using. I needed to do the same thing as you and managed it on ubuntu linux.

I needed it to update every 't' seconds, so I wrote a bash script with wget to download (and replace) the CSV file on a loop, and added a [CSV to HTML converter script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105501/convert-csv-to-html-table) to the end of my own, replacing "Medical.csv" with the file previously downloaded. All the "echo"s were piped to a output.html

Now I have an HTML being regularly updated with the values of the CSV from the website